# Excel - Data Validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet which requires dynamically updating lists for user input. The user input will be entered, for example, on the 'Master' sheet. Users will enter a workflow name in master, and a VLOOKUP will pull the unique workflow ID. In a later column, I need a data validation cell to find the unique workflow ID and then provide a list of unique task IDs for the given workflow ID.

In a separate sheet, 'Refs', I have used UNIQUE(FILTER) to find the unique task IDs for each unique workflow ID. However, my data validation is using absolute references and so it is finding the first workflow ID and only allowing users to task IDs associated with the first workflow ID value. I need a way to drag my data validation rule down, but have the list it is looking for move across my column.

Cell I1 in Refs, for example, is pulling the first workflow ID (H5 in Master). Cell J1 Refs pulls H6 in Master etc. The data in Master moves down by row, the unique lists in Refs moves along by column. The unique lists then begin in row 3 of Refs.

Will I need to manually update the data validation in the Master sheet for each row for it to pick up on the next column along? I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but frankly I'm close to 7 hours down the rabbit hole on this one and can't see the forest for the trees.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/conditional-formatting/conditional-data-validation

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you - this got me on to the path of just transposing the data in Refs. Once done, it became much easier to manage!